# ion-infinite-scroll inside ion-list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement ion-infinite-scroll in my ionic 3 application. i need to implement it inside a ion-list. i made my scroll-content overflow:hidden and make ion-list overflow-y: scroll.

My HTML Code:

```
<ion-content fullscreen padding>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let passanger of passangers" (click) = "gotoPassangerDetails(passanger.bookingNo)">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col">{{passanger.lastName}}</div>
            <div class = "col">{{passanger.firstName}}</div>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-infinite-scroll style="background-color: white" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" infinite-scroll-parent="true">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data..." position="top" ></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-list>
```

My CSS

```
page-customer-list {
.scroll-content {;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ion-content{
    .row{
        .col.center{
            text-align: center;
        }
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    ion-list{
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 75%;
    }
}}
```

I am not able to get the trigger on doInfinite. if i am removing overflow:hidden in scroll -content it is working. but my whole page is scrolling.  i need to scroll only the content inside ion-list.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your ion-list with ion-scroll if you only want to make your list scroll. To make your list scroll vertically wrap your list inside:-

```
<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
</ion-scroll>
```

Check below link for more info:-

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/

Edit:- Try below code

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let passanger of passangers" (click)="gotoPassangerDetails(passanger.bookingNo)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">{{passanger.lastName}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{passanger.firstName}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll style="background-color: white" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data..." position="top"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Also remove all code from your CSS. It's not necessary.

Check below link for official infinite-scroll sample:-

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. My bad luck its not working as i expected.. i need to scroll only inside a list and in that scroll end ionInfinite shoul get called.. Could you please give me sample

Comment: `<ion-scroll scrollY="true"> .... </ion-scroll>` this does all the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Carlos.V You're Welcome. Glad it helped.